# Start parallel processes from within a function

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to start multiple processes by calling a single function:

what I want to put the following inside a function and only have to call that function:

```py
def func():
    print("hey")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes = []
    processes.append(Process(target=func))
    processes.append(Process(target=func))

    for process in processes:
        process.start()
```

what the code looks like:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager


def multi():
    def func():
        print("hey")

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        processes = []
        processes.append(Process(target=func))
        processes.append(Process(target=func))

        for process in processes:
            process.start()

#Run function
multi()
```

The error I get:

```py
new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File *path*, line 82, in steal_handle
    _winapi.PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, False, source_pid)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

Comment: Error is not reproducible for me on linux machine.

Comment: Your code and your traceback don't seem to be related.

Comment: should have included that I am running it on windows

Comment: You can move `func` delcaration outside of `multi`.

Comment: Your `if __name__ == '__main__'` **MUST** be at the top level. Change your code to: `if __name__ == '__main__': multi()`.

Comment: - Poojan
That does indeed seem to work, would be pretty neat to have it be an inner-function tho

Comment: @Bakuriu can't get that to work can you write the code as an answer?

Comment: @Floxxy ***"MUST be at the top level."***: Read [tutorial - executing-modules-as-scripts](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

The main function need not be done inside of multi function. Also if you want func to be multiprocessed put it outside of multi. You can rewrite the code as:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def func():
    print("hey")

def multi():
    procs=[]
    no_of_processes=2 #say
    for i in range(no_of_processes):
        Process(target=func).start()

    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()

if __name__=='__main__':
    multi()
```